# HTML report using Junit and Ant with pass column

Tags: junit, junit3

How to show count  of pass test cases in HTML report of J unit

Comment: I am able to generate HTML Report but i want to show count of pass test case in report .Please help me on this . Thanks!!

Comment: How are you executing JUnit? Is this through a build script (Ant, Maven etc) or through as IDE (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, Netbeans etc). Your comment also indicated you can generate a report - what are you using to do that?

Comment: i am using Ant script .